# Number of packets sent and received on an interface

Tags: linux, shell-script, networking, network-interface

I'm interested in creating a script which prints total number of received packets and sent packets on an interface. The output should be like:

```
interface
TX: number
RX: number
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you mean something like tcpdump?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far and any issues/errors that you faced? This should be simple. You can start with `ifconfig`, `grep` and `awk`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can figure out the amount of packets received and transmitted across `eth0` by running the following commands:

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_packets
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_packets
```

You could then use this fact to write simple a shell script which will poll these files every second, and then calculate and output a PPS value (packets per second).

Comment: The "simple shell script" has an example: https://www.unixteacher.org/blog/display-packets-per-second-on-linux/ . I've seen elsewhere `ethtool -S` showing packets per second, but I don't get that on Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some miss matches in the stats using the **/sys/class/net** statistics and also same with

```
    ifconfig <interface>
```

(since it is reading stats from that files, i think). Some tools using the mentioned counters are `nload` and `vnstat`.

The correct stats i have seen is from

```
    ethtool -S <interface> | grep -E 'rx_packets|tx_packets|rx_bytes|tx_bytes'
```

Comment: On Ubuntu I only see total packets, not packets per second, as I've seen in an online example. I wonder if this is distribution dependent...

Comment: @Nagev works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.